# How to substitute values in SymPy object?

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I have a linear system to be solved by `SymPy`, I wrote the augmented matrix as a SymPy object.

```
a, b, c = sy.symbols('a, b, c', real = True)
A = sy.Matrix([[1, 2, -3, a], [4, -1, 8, b], [2, -6, -4, c]])
A
```

And I get this

[image]

Now I perform row reduced echelon form, and I am interested in expression in the red box:

```
A_rref = A.rref()
A_rref
```

[image]

I try to use `a = sy.Interger(3), b = sy.Interger(6),c = sy.Interger(7)`, but how to substitute these values to evaluate expression in the red box?

And also I check the type of expression in the red box. What kind of object is this?

```
In[13]: type(A_rref[0][0,3])
 Out[13]: sympy.core.add.Add
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To substitute values, you can use [`subs`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution) with a dictionary mapping each variable to its value.

Note that using `sy.Integer(1)` or similar expressions is only needed when [working with fractions of constants](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers), to avoid that Python converts those fractions to floats before sympy can get its grip on it.

```py
import sympy as sy

a, b, c = sy.symbols('a, b, c', real = True)
A = sy.Matrix([[1, 2, -3, a], [4, -1, 8, b], [2, -6, -4, c]])
A_rref = A.rref()
print(A_rref[0].subs({a: 3, b: 6, c: 7}))
```

Output:

```py
Matrix([[1, 0, 0, 31/14],
        [0, 1, 0, -16/91],
        [0, 0, 1, -69/182]])
```

To find out about how sympy expressions are built up, [`srepr`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html) comes in handy:

```py
print(sy.srepr(A_rref[0][0,3]))
```

Which gives:

```
Add(Mul(Rational(2, 7), Symbol('a', real=True)), Mul(Rational(1, 7), Symbol('b', real=True)), Mul(Rational(1, 14), Symbol('c', real=True)))
```

So, the expression is a tree of sub expressions. At the highest level, there is a sum, so that's what's shown when printing the `type`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59818945/12046409) contains some code to draw the expression tree as a text diagram:

```
    +---> symbol Rational(1, 7)
    |   
    +---> symbol Symbol('b', real=True)
    |   
+---+ function <class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'> had 2 arguments
|   
|   +---> symbol Rational(1, 14)
|   |   
|   +---> symbol Symbol('c', real=True)
|   |   
+---+ function <class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'> had 2 arguments
|   
|   +---> symbol Rational(2, 7)
|   |   
|   +---> symbol Symbol('a', real=True)
|   |   
+---+ function <class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'> had 2 arguments
|   
+ function <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> had 3 arguments
```